# How do/should LiPo low-voltage cutoffs deal with voltage sag in practice?

Tags: batteries

I've seen a lot of literature online about low-voltage cutoffs for lithium polymer batteries, but they hardly mention anything about the effects and considerations of voltage sag caused by the battery's internal resistance while under load. This all stems from the internal resistance of the battery.

For high-power applications, the voltage sag can be quite considerable and lead to premature cutoff in a variety of ways. For example, a 20A draw on a 2S lipo with an internal resistance of 10mOhms gives a sag of 0.2VDC, which is 10% of the usable voltage range of the battery! (6.4-8.4VDC).

1. Do most LVCs implement a low pass filter on the measured pack voltage to avoid a short current spike tripping the LVC prematurely?
2. Do LVCs simply monitor the raw output voltage of the pack (which may be sagged)? Could they instead use an assumed internal resistance, measure current draw and output voltage, and estimate the true pack voltage?

**EDIT:** Specs say to not discharge a cell below 3.0VDC. But does this spec apply to the pack output voltage while under load, or the true internal voltage with internal resistance and load accounted for?